# QMK RGB saturation bottoms out

Tags: c, keyboard, qmk, qmk-firmware

[RGB keycodes](https://beta.docs.qmk.fm/using-qmk/hardware-features/lighting/feature_rgblight#keycodes) `RGB_HUI`, `RGB_HUD`, `RGB_SAI`, `RGB_SAD`, `RGB_VAI`, and `RGB_VAD` allow me to increment or decrement hue, saturation, and value on my RGB underglow lights. But I wanted to be able to *hold down* a key to change the color *continually*. So I made these changes:

In `config.h`:

```
#ifdef RGBLIGHT_ENABLE
  #define RGBLIGHT_HUE_STEP 1
  #define RGBLIGHT_SAT_STEP 1
  #define RGBLIGHT_VAL_STEP 1
#endif
```

And then in `keymap.c` I made the custom keycodes:

```
enum custom_keycodes {
    KC_HUI = SAFE_RANGE,
    KC_HUD,
    KC_SAI,
    KC_SAD,
    KC_VAI,
    KC_VAD
};
```

And defined some variables:

```
// flags. 0 = no change, 1 = increment, -1 = decrement.
int8_t change_hue = 0;
int8_t change_saturation = 0;
int8_t change_value = 0;

// timers to control color change speed
uint16_t hue_timer = 0;
uint16_t saturation_timer = 0;
uint16_t value_timer = 0;

// seconds it takes to cycle through 0-255 or back
// technically 1 = 1.024 seconds, yielding even multiples of 4ms per tick (1024 / 256).
const int8_t hue_seconds = 5;
const int8_t saturation_seconds = 5;
const int8_t value_seconds = 5;
```

Then I use the keycodes to set the flags and timers:

```
bool process_record_user(uint16_t keycode, keyrecord_t *record) {
    switch (keycode) {
        case KC_HUI:
            if (record->event.pressed) {
                hue_timer = timer_read();
                change_hue = 1;
            } else {
                change_hue = 0;
            }
            break;
        case KC_HUD:
            if (record->event.pressed) {
                hue_timer = timer_read();
                change_hue = -1;
            } else {
                change_hue = 0;
            }
            break;
        case KC_SAI:
            if (record->event.pressed) {
                saturation_timer = timer_read();
                change_saturation = 1;
            } else {
                change_saturation = 0;
            }
            break;
        case KC_SAD:
            if (record->event.pressed) {
                saturation_timer = timer_read();
                change_saturation = -1;
            } else {
                change_saturation = 0;
            }
            break;
        case KC_VAI:
            if (record->event.pressed) {
                value_timer = timer_read();
                change_value = 1;
            } else {
                change_value = 0;
            }
            break;
        case KC_VAD:
            if (record->event.pressed) {
                value_timer = timer_read();
                change_value = -1;
            } else {
                change_value = 0;
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then I use a matrix scan to change the color using those flags and timers:

```
void matrix_scan_user(void) {
    switch (change_hue) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            if (timer_elapsed(hue_timer) > (hue_seconds * 4)) {
                hue_timer = timer_read();
                rgblight_increase_hue();
            }
            break;
        case -1:
            if (timer_elapsed(hue_timer) > (hue_seconds * 4)) {
                hue_timer = timer_read();
                rgblight_decrease_hue();
            }
            break;
    }
    switch (change_saturation) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            if (timer_elapsed(saturation_timer) > (saturation_seconds * 4)) {
                saturation_timer = timer_read();
                rgblight_increase_sat();
            }
            break;
        case -1:
            if (timer_elapsed(saturation_timer) > (saturation_seconds * 4)) {
                saturation_timer = timer_read();
                rgblight_decrease_sat();
            }
            break;
    }
    switch (change_value) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            if (timer_elapsed(value_timer) > (value_seconds * 4)) {
                value_timer = timer_read();
                rgblight_increase_val();
            }
            break;
        case -1:
            if (timer_elapsed(value_timer) > (value_seconds * 4)) {
                value_timer = timer_read();
                rgblight_decrease_val();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

According to [the docs](https://beta.docs.qmk.fm/using-qmk/hardware-features/lighting/feature_rgblight#hue-sat-val-change), each of those should wrap around at the max/min hue/saturation/value, respectively.

- That seems to work exactly as expected with `KC_HUI` and `KC_HUD`: If I hold the key down long enough it rounds the bend and hue just keeps on cycling through.
- `KC_SAI`, `KC_VAI`, and `KC_VAD` work at least normal-ish. I can increase saturation or value to the max and it will just stop there, and likewise if I decrement the value it stops at zero.
- `KC_SAD` is the problem. When I hold it down long enough (just past white), the keyboard bombs out. It turns a weird orange color and nothing works.

For reference, here is the [GitHub commit](https://github.com/BenjaminWolfe/qmk_firmware/commit/59939993b3eab4af904ca31a58e273f9ab153386) where I made all the changes, along with the rest of my code of course.

1. Any idea why `KC_SAD` would bomb out rather than either stopping or wrapping around?
2. Any idea why both saturation and value just stop, rather than wrapping around as I'd expect based on my read of the docs?
3. Might I do better to try this whole thing a different way (question to more seasoned users)?

Comment: FI: [Kyria](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/blob/master/keyboards/splitkb/kyria/readme.md) is in 'splitkb', [qmk_firmware/keyboards/splitkb/kyria/](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware/tree/master/keyboards/splitkb/kyria). It is [AVR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR)-based ([Pro Micro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems#Software-compatibility_only)).

Answer (score 1):

I experimented with this some more, and came up with a different implementation which is much more efficient in terms of lines of code and bytes added to the firmware size. Note that instead of defining new custom keycodes, instead it hijacks the existing RGB_... ones for this new and improved purpose:

```c
#include <lib/lib8tion/lib8tion.h>

// flags. 0 = no change, 1 = increment, -1 = decrement.
int8_t change_hue = 0;
int8_t change_sat = 0;
int8_t change_val = 0;

// timer to control color change speed
uint16_t change_timer = 0;
const uint16_t change_tick  = 15;

void matrix_scan_user(void) {
    if (change_hue != 0 || change_val != 0 || change_sat != 0) {
        if (timer_elapsed(change_timer) > change_tick) {
            HSV hsv = rgblight_get_hsv();
            hsv.h += change_hue;
            hsv.s = change_sat > 0 ? qadd8(hsv.s, (uint8_t) change_sat) : qsub8(hsv.s, (uint8_t) -change_sat);
            hsv.v = change_val > 0 ? qadd8(hsv.v, (uint8_t) change_val) : qsub8(hsv.v, (uint8_t) -change_val);
            rgblight_sethsv_noeeprom(hsv.h, hsv.s, hsv.v);
            change_timer = timer_read();
        }
    }
}

bool process_record_user(uint16_t keycode, keyrecord_t *record) {
    if (record->event.pressed) {
        switch (keycode) {

                // clang-format off
            case RGB_HUI: change_timer = timer_read(); change_hue =  1; return false;
            case RGB_HUD: change_timer = timer_read(); change_hue = -1; return false;
            case RGB_SAI: change_timer = timer_read(); change_sat =  1; return false;
            case RGB_SAD: change_timer = timer_read(); change_sat = -1; return false;
            case RGB_VAI: change_timer = timer_read(); change_val =  1; return false;
            case RGB_VAD: change_timer = timer_read(); change_val = -1; return false;
                // clang-format on
        }
    } else {
        bool rgb_done = false;
        switch (keycode) {
            case RGB_HUI:
            case RGB_HUD:
                change_hue = 0;
                rgb_done   = true;
                break;
            case RGB_SAI:
            case RGB_SAD:
                change_sat = 0;
                rgb_done   = true;
                break;
            case RGB_VAI:
            case RGB_VAD:
                change_val = 0;
                rgb_done   = true;
                break;
        }

        if (rgb_done) {
            HSV final = rgblight_get_hsv();
            rgblight_sethsv(final.h, final.s, final.v);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for this! A few questions and notes if I may. Why add change_sat and change_val when positive, and subtract when negative? Wouldn't that always increment? Does the \_rgb mean those can be separate from other matrix_scan_user and process_record_user code? When you check the value of rgb_done, under what circumstances would it be false? Looks like it might mishandle holding one RGB\_ key while pressing another (b/c it's all one timer), but I'm OK with that for all the gains. Finally, have I potentially damaged my keyboard with so many writes to eeprom? Or just the current session?

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer! To answer my own questions for the record... you used qadd8 in one place and qsub8 in the other, so if worked. The `matrix_scan_user` and `process_record_user` code (now renamed from having `_rgb` appended to them) should be added into any other such code I have. That in itself is a good reason for `rgb_done`, since surely I'll have macros for other keys. Yes it will mishandle me pressing more than one at once, and that's fine. And yes, based on your comments on Discord, I was actually wearing out my processor!

Comment: `qadd8` and `qsub8` only work with `unsigned int8_t` - you cannot pass a negative number to them. 

As for damage, it might have worn your eeprom a bit.  I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really nice bit of functionality!

1. I copied your code into one of my keyboards, and I am not able to reproduce the `"bomb out"` behavior that you are seeing on `KC_SAD`.
2. The documentation is incorrect. The increase/decrease functions for saturation and value do not wrap around, and to my knowledge, they are not intended to wrap. They max out at 255, and are bottom limited at 0. I'll be filing a [PR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control#Pull_requests) to fix the documentation.
3. The only significant problem that I see with your implementation is that it results in *very* many writes to [EEPROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEPROM), and that isn't healthy (they wear out over time). You should use, for instance, `rgblight_increase_sat_noeeprom()` to adjust the saturation (and its counterparts for hue / saturation, and for decrease). Then when you release the key, only then should you write the current [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) setting to EEPROM (using `rgblight_sethsv()` to set the final value into EEPROM.